# Child Routers durandal 2 HTML StarterKit

Tags: routes, durandal-2.0

i trying to create child routes in durandal 2 starterkit as shown in http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Using-The-Router/   without success.

i want to habe something like http://mywebsite.com/#blog/post1/

so in my app i have in viewmodel a shell file   viewmodel/shell.js

```
{ route: 'blog*details', title:'Blog', moduleId: 'blog/index', nav: 2, hash: '#blog' },
```

and

in app/blog/

i have

```
index.js 
       index.js
       default/index.js
       default/index.html
```

why is it not working what am i doing wrong ?

thx

EDIT:

this is how my shell.js looks like

```
define(['plugins/router', 'durandal/app'], function (router, app) {

    return {
        router: router,
        attached : attached,
        search: function() {
            //It's really easy to show a message box.
            //You can add custom options too. Also, it returns a promise for the user's response.
            app.showMessage('Search not yet implemented...');
        },
        activate: function () {
            router.map([
                { route: '', title:'Home', moduleId: 'viewmodels/home', nav: 1 },
                { route: 'blog*route', title:'Blog', moduleId: 'blog/index', nav: 2, hash: '#blog' }
            ]).buildNavigationModel();

            return router.activate();
        },
        footerLinks : [
          ...
       ]
    };

      function attached() {

    }//=======attached end
});
```

Comment: can you show some more code. We seem to be missing where you are creating your child router etc.

Comment: @Excommunicated here you are

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is you will need to create a child router to handle your splat routes `blog*details`
in your index.js file (so app/blog/index.js) you will need to create the child router like so.

```
define(['plugins/router'],function(router){
    var childRouter = router.createChildRouter().makeRelative({ moduleId: 'blog', fromParent: true})
        .map([
            ...insert routes here...
        ]).buildNavigationModel();
    return {
        router: childRouter
    };
});
```

from then you can create all your routes like blog/post1, blog/post2 etc. Take a look at the samples in the ko folder of the [HTML Samples.zip download](http://durandaljs.com/pages/downloads/)